# Safari Private Browsing and gmail

Tags: macos, gmail, safari

I have two gmail accounts. If I follow the following steps then Safari will not let me log in to any other gmail account

1. Go the gmail, log in as user1
2. Enable Private browsing
3. Go to one website
4. Disable Private browsing
5. Go to gmail and logout.

At this point gmail will not let me switch to user2. I have to quit the whole browser before I get that option.

Is there a way to fix this?

I am not trying to open two gmail accounts at the same time. Just one after the other. As long as I do not enter Private Browsing mode between the two logins I can switch between account1 and account2.

Also, I am not changing browser to Firefox

Comment: Try opening a new browser window and enabling private browsing there.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 2):

I would make this a comment, but don't have enough rep. Google recently enabled [multiple sign-in](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181599) for gmail and other products, allowing you to switch from account to account without signing out. I know this doesnt answer your specific issue, but it might be worthwhile to check out.

Answer (score 0):

As Force flow suggested, open a new browser, activate private mode, then deactivate it. Now click sign in as a different user. This works for me.